# animation with sprite 2D android

Tags: android

I am building a virtual store with the effect same like this

[enter link description here](http://www.htc.com/au/smartphones/)

The user can freely rotate the image from left to right and top to bottom or vice versa. I suppose to use sprite 2D to implement that animation. There are some tutorials I found but because Im pretty new about graphic programming so could anyone point me to the correct way that approach my expected performance. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use the [Canvas](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html) API in Android. [Here](http://www.edu4java.com/androidgame/androidgame4.html) is an example of how to use it with sprites.